# Disable double click selection

Tags: html, css, double-click

In some cases, I make the `<li>` or `<span class="icon">` elements clickable, but if the use clicks twice, it kinda messes around and show the blue selection a little everywhere :/

The solution I came with are:

1- wrap the element within a `<a href="javascript:;">`

2- use the css property: `user-select: none;`

I'd like to ask you if there is a better solution than the above.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not adding the `user-select: none;` directly to your `li`?

Comment: it's the solution #2 I proposed, but I wanted to know if there is another way to do it, to prevent adding `user-select` all the time

Comment: Add a CSS class which holds `user-select: none;` and add it to `ul` instead of `li`. Your solution is the way to go :)

Comment: OK, i'll go with that solution ;)

Answer (score -4):

Try with `user-select: none;`. It should help (include within your `<li>` itself).

If you are using node, then there are few inbuilt options.

Comment: It is nothing new to OP